# how to download a web page with ajax calls

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-scraping

I'd like to download the list of all headline articles in here,
http://seekingalpha.com/symbol/amzn

but there is a button 'MORE' making Ajax call.
Is there a way that I can download full list of articles?

I'm not familiar with javascript or Ajax, so any advice will be very helpful.

Here's the javascript function for the button.

```
function portfolioPagination(type, page, direction){
  if ($(type + '_show_more')) {
    $(type + '_show_more').remove();
    $('show-more-preloader').style.display = "";
  }
  if (page == 0) return;
  new Ajax.Updater({success: 'headlines_'+type}, '/account/ajax_headlines_content', {
    parameters: { type: type, page: page, slugs: 'amzn', is_symbol_page : true},
    insertion: 'bottom',
    onComplete: function(){$('show-more-preloader').style.display = "none";}
  });
  if (window.pageTracker) pageTracker._trackEvent("Portfolio Tracking", 'Pagination', type+" - "+direction);
}
```

Comment: Yes it is possible, however it is not a problem you're facing. You're asking us to write your code for you. What is the specific part you're having trouble with?

Comment: Check whether the site provides an API, instead of trying to read the HTML web page.

Comment: Sorry, my question was not very specific. I didn't know where to start, so I was asking which part I should modify, or how to make a manual query and how to send it to the server. And thanks, I'll check if they provide an API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Chrome inspector or Firebug or something similar to see the AJAX request, probably something like `../account/ajax_headlines_content/..` and look at result of that request. There's the data you want.

--

The URL is: http://seekingalpha.com/account/ajax_headlines_content

The data is (Form Data):

```
type: all
page: 2
slugs: amzn
is_symbol_page: true
_:
```

It looks like it accepts `$_GET` as well: http://seekingalpha.com/account/ajax_headlines_content?type=all&page=2&slugs=amzn&is_symbol_page=true&_=

Comment: Thank you for the answer! using $_GET will be much easier for me.